# iOS Simulator - iOs 10/Xcode 8.3/Swift 3 - Location service issues on webview in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, gpx

I have implemented webView in my iOS app which renders a website. The website uses location services and renders geocodes on a map.

So far, when I go to webview screen, it prompts 2 location alerts  1) from App - Need approval to use location service 2) From Website url - Need approval to use location service.

My issues are:

1) Why does it show two popups (for app and for website) asking for approval for location service? Is it iOS standard (specifically website url)?

2) Even though I get both popups and I approve it, still location page doesn't render map and geocodes in simulator. It works in actual device.

3) I also get following error when rendering website in webview: 
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (KCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824). 
Even though webpage is loaded in simulator, does it have anything to do with the location service not working?

So far I have done:
1) Added test.gpx file as suggested by other threads.
2) Added "Location When In Use Usage Description" in info.plist

I searched all threads but couldn't find relevant information. You can point to one if you know. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Regards to #2? Why would you think a simulator has a GPS? (This one I know to be true. How exactly should a simulator on a Mac use GPS when that's part of the cellular system?)  Regards to #3? Since you already know #2 works in an actual device, does this work too? It's probably important to the answer.

Comment: Simulator does not have GPS but as I mentioned above, I have added simulated location data using GPX file with lats and longs, which is not being used. The website which I am rendering in simulator is only available on intranet( not in production) and device doesn't have access to intranet so I am not able to test actual website in device.

Comment: I resolved the issue. The google map url was being blocked by network settings.